# How to get the nth line from a string?

Tags: c#

I have a string

```
 UNCON1\r\nMCF\r\n10/16/14 21:08:40\r\n4452 LANCASTER DR NE\r\nM32, 
E305\r\nMCF201410160019\r\n
```

I want result `4452 LANCASTER DR NE`. It's always on the 4th line.

I am doing by this way

```
private void Test(string msg)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        msg = msg.Substring(msg.IndexOf("\\r\\n")).Substring(4);
    }
    string address = msg.Remove(msg.IndexOf("\\r\\n"));
}
```

Is there any good way to do this, Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the rule, why do you want `4452 LANCASTER DR NE`?

Comment: its address, It always occur in 4th line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you want the 4th line. First [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) the string by `Environment.NewLine`, then use the indexer on the array:

```
string[] lines = str.Split(new []{ Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string address = lines[3];  // or safe: lines.ElementAtOrDefault(3)
```

Use    `StringSplitOptions.None` if you also want to count empty lines (if possible):

Answer (score 1):

Just `Split` the string into its component lines.  Try:

```
msg.Split(new char[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[3];
```

Documentation on `Split`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
string address = msg.Split("\r\n")[3];
```

Comment: Downvoted since "\n" and not "\r\n" so with your code he would get a "\r" on the end of his string.